# SqlServer query using Group by and Order by

Tags: sql-server

```
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 rn,
        SUM(BILL_DETAIL.x_bill_quantity)      as BILL_QUANTITY,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_to)        as BILLABLE_TO,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_yn)        as BILLABLE_YN,
        AVG(BILL_DETAIL.x_bill_rate)          as BILL_RATE,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_cost_rate)          as COST_RATE,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_cost_total)          as COST_TYPE,
        LISTAGG(BILL_DETAIL.objid, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY BILL_DETAIL.objid) as ID_LIST
     FROM  table_x_gsa_bill_detail BILL_DETAIL
      WHERE (1=1)
       GROUP BY (DECODE(BILLABLE_YN, 1, 'Billable', 'Non-Billable') || ',' || BILLABLE_TO  || ',' || DETAIL_CLASS || ',' || COST_TYPE || ',' || BILL_RATE) 
      ORDER BY DECODE(BILLABLE_YN, 1, 'Billable', 'Non-Billable') || ',' || BILLABLE_TO  || ',' || DETAIL_CLASS || 
  ) dt
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```

How can I use `Case` keyword instead of `Decode` in the above query ? I am not able to convert above query for group by and order by..

Actually i need to do group by the aggregate values which i got  from the fields of  `BILLABLE_YN,BILLABLE_TO,DETAIL_CLASS, COST_TYPE, BILL_RATE`.

Whereas in Oracle I can run above query using `decode` keyword but in SQL Server I am not able to use `BILLABLE_YN` field alias of above query in group by .

I tried using following way but it is wrong because here I am not using aggregate values of fields in group by function. How can I  convert the query to SQL Server syntax ?

```
GROUP BY (case BILLABLE_YN
          when 1 then 'Billable'
          when 0 then 'Non-Billable'
          else 'Non-Billable' End BILLABLE_YN  + ',' + BILLABLE_TO  + ',' + DETAIL_CLASS + ',' + COST_TYPE + ',' + BILL_RATE)
```

Comment: like that? GROUP BY CASE BILLABLE_YN WHEN 1 THEN 'Billable' ELSE  'Non-Billable' END + ',' + BILLABLE_TO  + ',' + DETAIL_CLASS + ',' + COST_TYPE + ',' + BILL_RATE

Comment: if i tried like that its getting error as BILLABLE_YN invalid column

Comment: Can you pls help me how to convert LISTAGG(BILL_DETAIL.objid, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY BILL_DETAIL.objid) as ID_LIST using stuff key work ??  that need to be included in this query !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY CASE MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_yn) 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Billable' ELSE 'Non-Billable' END + ',' +
MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_to) + ',' + DETAIL_CLASS + ',' + 
MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_cost_total) + ',' + AVG(BILL_DETAIL.x_bill_rate)
```

I have no idea what the `LISTAGG` function is. If you need to split the string column they search it on that site. There were a lot of topics like that.

Comment: iam getting following Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: an you pls modify that query for SQlserver 

can you pls run following query at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9ec9f/4  i tried created and tables and fields and data for running following query in the above link. i just need alternative keyword need to be used instead of ListAgg in sqlserver query and groupby and orderby need to used in proper way to run following.   iam able to run following query in oracle but struggling to run in sqlserver database. pls help me.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 rn,
        SUM(BILL_DETAIL.x_bill_quantity)      as BILL_QUANTITY,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_to)        as BILLABLE_TO,
        MIN(BILL_DETAIL.x_billable_yn)        as BILLABLE_YN,
        AVG(BILL_DETAIL.x_bill_rate)          as BILL_RATE,
       
        LISTAGG(BILL_DETAIL.objid, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY BILL_DETAIL.objid) as ID_LIST

Comment: FROM   BILL_DETAIL
      WHERE (1=1)
 GROUP BY (DECODE(x_billable_yn, 1, 'Billable', 'Non-Billable') + ',' + x_billable_to  +  ',' + COST_TYPE + ',' + x_bill_rate)
      ORDER BY DECODE(x_billable_yn, 1, 'Billable', 'Non-Billable') + ',' + x_billable_to  +  ',' + COST_TYPE + ',' + x_bill_rate
       )dt 
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 1